# C++ : N line segment Intersection

Tags: computational-geometry

I need to find intersection of *N* line segments (given by coordinates of start and end points) which are either vertical or horizontal.So I read that *Sweep Line Algorithm* is a good way to solve this.

But I can't seem to find it's implementation in C++ anywhere on Internet. Can someone provide me it's code in C++ ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to find. N line segments may have many intersections. You need one of them? All of them? Something else?

Comment: Code requests are off-topic here, strict programming questions are also off-topic here.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I need all of the intersections.

Comment: There could be $O(N^2)$ intersections (consider a grid with $N/2$ rows and $N/2$ columns), in which case you need $O(N^2)$ time anyway, which you can achieve with the obvious test-all-pairs algorithm.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think you mean $\Theta$, not $O$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Correct, $\Theta$ (or $\Omega$) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long the lines are and what the likelihood of intersections is, you could also use a [spatial join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976437/980270). I.e. you treat all all lines as rectangles, put them in a spatial index and search for each line with which other lines it overlaps. You can use a standard R-Tree or Quadtree, but I would actually suggest a PH-Tree here, for example [this one](https://github.com/mcxme/phtree), because they are very fast for window queries with small result sets (for example if you expect usually only 1 intersection). For all results, you would have to manually calculate whether the lines actually intersect or not, because overlapping rectangles is an indicator for overlap, but obviously not a guarantee.

Also 'Sweep Line' is more of a general approach of tackling a problem, a bit like 'divide and conquer'. It is not an algorithm in itself, you would have to be more specific how you would use it to solve your intersection problem.

Comment: I need to find the  total number of intersection for every line.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with proposal? Is there a part that is not clear?

Comment: I used sweep line algorithm but I can't figure out how to store number of  intersections for every  line.